# Why does request.user get errors in a custom clean form?

Tags: python, django

Why does request.user in this db query get a global name 'request' is not defined error?
Both out side and inside the try definition?
This code is inside a custom clean definition:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):

    question= forms.CharField(label = ('question'))

    def clean_question(self):
        self.question = self.cleaned_data['question']
        self.question = self.question.lower()
        y = ''
        for c in self.question:
            if c != '?':
                y+=str(c)
        self.question = y
        try:
            QuestionModel.objects.get(question= self.question)
        except QuestionModel.DoesNotExist:
            x = QuestionModel(question= self.question)
            x.save()

        y = TheirAnswerModel.objects.get(user= request.user, question_id= x.id) #here

        try:
            x = QuestionModel.objects.get(question= self.question)
            y = TheirAnswerModel.objects.get(user= request.user, question_id= x.id) and here
            raise forms.ValidationError("You have already asked that question")
        except TheirAnswerModel.DoesNotExist:
            return self.question
```

Answer (score 2):

Where you are referencing `request` (notice it's not a parameter and hopefully not a global), it doesn't exist in the namespace. Django intentionally separates a form from the request object, so You'll need to create your own init method that takes it as a parameter.

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form): 

    question = forms.CharField(label = ('question'))


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_question(self):

        # this is the only line I modified (besides a little cleanup)
        request = self.request

        self.question = self.cleaned_data['question']
        self.question = self.question.lower()
        y = ''
        for c in self.question:
            if c != '?':
                y+=str(c)
        self.question = y
        try:
            QuestionModel.objects.get(question= self.question)
        except QuestionModel.DoesNotExist:
            x = QuestionModel(question= self.question)
            x.save()

        y = TheirAnswerModel.objects.get(user= request.user, question_id= x.id) #here

        try:
            x = QuestionModel.objects.get(question= self.question)
            y = TheirAnswerModel.objects.get(user= request.user, question_id= x.id) #and here
            raise forms.ValidationError("You have already asked that question")
        except TheirAnswerModel.DoesNotExist:
            return self.question
```

Perhaps not important, but your second try block doesn't make a lot of sense to me.